# How to view HTML Source?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying here - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/CRVpL/2/ - to view the source for a div.
The first line below picks up the html ok but the next line doesn't put it where I want.

```
 var inhtml = $('#box1').html();
 $(inhtml).appendTo('#displaysource');
```

Could someone point out the correct way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.text()`

```
 $('#displaysource').text(inhtml);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/awt58/)**

When you do `$(inhtml).appendTo(..` the html will append to the div as elements, but if you want to see it as text they needs to be escaped and thats what .text() does on html tags.

Comment: Also, `$('#displaysource').append(inhtml)` if you want the append part.

Answer (score 1):

```
var inhtml = $('#box1').html();
 $('#displaysource').text(inhtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inhtml = $('#box1').html();
 $(inhtml).appendTo('#displaysource');
```

TO

```
var inhtml = $('#box1');
$(inhtml).appendTo('#displaysource');
```

if you want to move the contents make this:

```
 var inhtml = $('#box1').text();
 $('#displaysource').text(inhtml);
```

Hope you can help